# How to synchronize a 1v1 realtime action online mini game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, synchronization, game-engine

### What I'm trying to make

Hi, game development newbie here. The game I am trying to make is fairly simple. It's almost exactly like the old FC game "Ballon Fight" except that I'm trying to make it online where players can go through a match making to find opponents.

BalloonFight:

[image: Ballon-Fight]

### What I Read

I have read some articles, and found most of them lead to two approaches:

1. **Put all game logic on the client**, and the client sends player inputs to server on every frame update. The server acts like a dispatcher which only makes sure player A's input is received by both client A and B. My understanding is that if we see the client in this case as a pure function, and if the two players' inputs are received by each other, the game should produce same results on both clients. Thus synchronization is achieved.
2. **Put all game logic on the server**, and let the server do the calculations and send back results to both clients. In this case, clients only worry about displaying.

### My Fears

Solution 1 sounded like a simpler one to me, but immediately I realized when network problem is put into account, it becomes incredibly complicated. Losing player A's connection for a few seconds means all the input is lost in that period. What I can guess is, to counter that, the server has to detect whether player A is lagged out and accumulate input from player B until player A is back then feed all the accumulated input to player A's client. Player A's client then need to do a fast forward to catch up. This sounds like there's huge amount of infra work on both client side and server side.

Solution 2 on the other hand looks very daunting to me, since for now I have only written some games on the client side.

### My questions

1. in order to make a simple online game like this, what is the most beginner friendly way to synchronize game state?
2. if I were to use solution 1 stated above, is there any framework that provides such infra so that I don't have to handle network issues all by myself?

In advance, thank you game dev gurus.

Comment: have you looked at the unity networking?  Lots of this stuff is built in and you tune it to your games needs. [unity link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html) while unet is to be removed theyve said now 2020, so, you have time

Comment: is there anything like that but for cocos2d?

Comment: Are you sure it doesnt work with cocos2d?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `unity3d` if you want to use cocos2d anyways?